# Unable to click element even though the selector returns a hit

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm using Node and Puppeteer to automate a third-party web application. Everything's fine until the script tries to click on an anchor tag (see HTML excerpt below).

This element has an id ("____ca"), and waitForSelector() finds it but calling the "click()" method using the same selector does nothing (no errors - nothing).

This anchor sits within a span which itself sits within another span and I've tried to click both of these with the same result, i.e., nothing happens.

Oddly, if you open the debugger on this page and use "document.querySelector('#____ca').click()", it works. So, why is it not working in Puppeteer?

Here is the HTML:

```
<a role="button" ct="Button" rel="tooltip" title="Give a badge" aria-label="Please Select Give a badge" data-toggle="cso-button" id="____ca" class="cso-btn cso-btn cso-action cso-corner cso-btn-grey   cso-btn-icon-icon-award  " href="javascript:void(0)" data-ctl-options="{&quot;actiontype&quot;:&quot;ACTION&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;Click&quot;,&quot;clientside&quot;:&quot;true&quot;}"><span class="cso-icon cso-btn-icon-award" style="margin-right:3px;"></span></a>
```

Here is the program in its entirety:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const url = '*************************************';

async function run() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);

    await page.$eval('#userNameBox', el => el.value = '*****');
    await page.$eval('#passWordBox', el => el.value = '*****')
    await page.click("#submit");

    await page.waitForSelector('.search-lnk');
    await page.click('.search-lnk');

    await page.waitForSelector('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptSearchEngines_ctl02_hlSearchEngine');
    await page.click('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptSearchEngines_ctl02_hlSearchEngine');

    await page.waitForSelector('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtsearch');
    await page.type('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtsearch', 'XYZ123');

    await page.click('.bd');

    await page.waitForSelector('#ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_lnkFullName');
    await page.click('#ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_lnkFullName');

    await page.waitForSelector('[data-tag="Feedback"]');
    await page.click('[data-tag="Feedback"]');

    await page.bringToFront();

    await page.waitForSelector('#____bm_508');
    await page.type('#____bm_508', 'Thank you for attending this conference!');

    await page.waitForSelector('#____ca');
    await page.click('#____ca');

    //browser.close();
}

run();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you copy & paste the relevent code in your question ?

Comment: Sorry about that. It's just a single line. All the other clicks on other elements work just fine. I also turned headless off so I could see what was going on as well as use the debugger to try and click it using the DOM (which works, as I mentioned earlier).

Comment: Do you call the click method after the waitForSelector method ?

Comment: Yes, I do use that method before the click()...

Comment: Please include the whole block in your question

Comment: I've included code for the entire program.